# How do I restrict the creation of an anonymous subclass (Java)

Tags: java, inheritance, anonymous

Sorry the question wasn't properly stated by me earlier. I try to implent the Factory Pattern. A better example: It is an abstract class Human with a function create. Based on the arguments that is passed to create it decides whether to return an instance of its subclass Man or an instance of subclass Woman. So you call create with: 
`Human john = Human.create("Man");`
The subclasses Man and Woman are inherited from the abstract class Human and are defined in the same file as Human. I don't want it to be possible to extend it by: `Human lisa = new Human("woman") {};` From the main program. Thanks!

EDIT:

Thanks for all the help! The solution I finally used was to let the class Human be public, as well as its function create. The Human constructor and the Man and Woman classes are declared "package-protected".

Comment: Do you want it to be possible to create a named subclass for A outside of P?

Comment: No I could do without that, as you can see now that I've edited my question I just want to create elements of the subclasses in the package by using create.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a visibility specifier in the class declaration for A and it will be a package access class.

**Edit to reflect change in question:**

Option 1:
Make the constructors for Human package private. By doing this, any class which attempts to extend Human outside of the package will fail because it can not call a constructor of the super class.

Option 2:
Stick with my original suggestion of a package private class and use instead a public access factory class.

Comment: Sorry the question was properly stated by me. I try to implent the Factory Pattern. A better example: It is an abstract class Human with a function create. Based on the arguments that is passed to create it decides whether to return an instance of its subclass Man or an instance of subclass Woman. So you call create with: 

Human john = Human.create("Man"); 

The subclasses Man and Woman are inherited from the abstract class Human and are defined in the same file as Human. I don't want it to be possible to extend it by:

Human lisa = new Human("woman") {};

From the main program. 

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry again it should say "NOT properly stated"... :-)

Comment: You should edit your question to reflect what you say here rather than just reply to the comment.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you mean by not possible. If you want it statically enforced, the only way to do that is to make the class package access, but that doesn't specifically limit anonymous classes - it limits named classes as well. If you want to enforce it at runtime, you can do this in the constructor of the abstract class

```
 if (this.getClass().isAnonymousClass() && !this.getClass().getName().startsWith(packageName)) {
     throw new IllegalStateException("This class cannot be used as an anonymous inner class");
  }
```

Comment: My question was badly stated, really sorry to waste your time due to that. But if you read the comment I replied to the first answer I hope I managed to describe my problem I a better way. This was a real cool way to do it though. 

Cheers!

Comment: This solution works great, thanks. I only needs to use the "if (this.getClass().isAnonymousClass())" part to achieve what i was looking for.

Comment: It would of course be nice to have an error at compile-time though.