# Java Factory pattern - How to prevent anonymous subclasses

Tags: java, factory, final

I'm doing a school assignment where I have to implement the Factory pattern. I have come a long way, but there is one last thing I have not been able to get working.

I have the following classes:

```
//Human.java
package human;
public abstract class Human{
    public static Human create(String namn, String pnr){
        char nastsist_char = pnr.charAt(9); // takes second last char in pnr
        String nastsist_string = Character.toString(nastsist_char);
        float siffra = Float.parseFloat(nastsist_string);   //Converts to float
        if ((siffra % 2) == 0){                 //Checks if even
            return new Woman(namn, pnr);            
        }
        else{
            return new Man(namn, pnr);
        }

    }

}

//Man.java
package human;
class Man extends Human{
    private final String pnr;
    private final String namn;

    protected Man(String n, String p){
        namn = n;
        pnr = p;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return "My name is "+namn+" and I am a man.";
    }   
}

//Woman.java
package human;
class Woman extends Human{
    private final String pnr;
    private final String namn;

    protected Woman(String n, String p){
        namn = n;
        pnr = p;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return "My name is "+namn+" and I am a woman.";
    }

}
```

I also have a class called `Test.java`. Here comes my problem: In Test.java, I want to make it impossible to do the following:

```
Human h = new Human(){};
```

i.e., to create an anonymous subclass of Human. Unfortunately, this line of code runs just fine, and an anonymous subclass is created. How can I make this line of code unexecutable/uncompilable?

PS. I have already tried making `Human` final. It was not allowed to combine `final` with `abstract` in a class.

EDIT:

So I got the tip to make the Human constructor protected. Here's what it looks like after the change:

```
//Human.java
package human;
public abstract class Human{
    protected Human(){}

    public static Human create(String name, String idNumber){
        char secondlast_char = idNumber.charAt(9); // takes second last char in pnr
        String secondlast_string = Character.toString(secondlast_char);
        float siffra = Float.parseFloat(secondlast_string); //Converts to float
        if ((siffra % 2) == 0){                 //Checks if even
            return new Woman(name, idNumber);           
        }
        else{
            return new Man(name, idNumber);
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I still do not get an error neither when running or compiling the code of Test.java, which by the way looks like this:

```
import human.*;
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Human h = new Human(){};
    }
}
```

Comment: P.S. this isn't a factory pattern, it's a `static` method factory pattern.

Comment: If I make it private, I get compiling errors in Man.java and Woman.java

Comment: See the edit in my question as to why this does not solve my problem.

Comment: Sorry for my stupid answer. The constructor must of course be package-private, as Boris correctly said. @BoristheSpider you should make that an answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I restrict the creation of an anonymous subclass (Java)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2692343/how-do-i-restrict-the-creation-of-an-anonymous-subclass-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a constructor with the **default** visibility:

```
public abstract class Human {        
    Human(){}    
}
```

By default this only allows access to classes **within the same package** so it is known as "package private".

Answer (score 0):

Use the default modifier for constructors:

```
Human(){}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that making it impossible to create anonymous classes from your base class is not the main problem with your implementation of the [Factory Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern). The pattern's intention is to **encapsulate object creation logic**, so that it can be changed easily without affecting the classes that are being instantiated nor the clients that use those instances.

Putting a static factory method into a base class that creates concrete instances of its sub classes defeats the objective of class separation thanks to inheritance as well as the purpose of the factory pattern.

I would seriously consider sticking your factory method into a separate class, e.g. `HumanFactoryImpl` and provide a corresponding interface.